# How to fix pre-commit hook failed error message

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gatsby, prettier, husky

I'm getting this error when trying to make commits on vscode, using gatsby. Does anyone know to go about it?

```
  ✔ Preparing...
  ❯ Running tasks...
    ❯ Running tasks for *.{js,css,json,md}
      ✖ prettier --write
    ↓ Running tasks for *.js [skipped]
      → No staged files match *.js
  ↓ Applying modifications... [skipped]
    → Skipped because of errors from tasks.
  ✔ Reverting to original state because of errors...
  ✔ Cleaning up...



⚠ prettier was terminated with SIGABRT
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
Aborted
```

Comment: you find the issue and solution here?

Comment: it looks like your `prettier --write` step is failing, so husky is doing exactly what it is supposed to. Does prettier run correctly from the vscode terminal, and is your repo free of prettier errors?